# Laravel retrieve data with with related tables

Tags: database, laravel, syntax, relationship, linktable

I want to show all industries, major, and skills that belong to the selected user. I'm stuck with the syntax. this is my code. the first row is correct but all other rows i need to link the user. eg: $major->myUsers->mySkills as $skills

```
@foreach($user->myIndustries as $industry)
       <h4> {{ $industry->title }}</h4>  <br>
        @foreach( $industry->myMajors as $major)
           <B>{{ $major->title }} - </B>
            @foreach($major->mySkills->unique() as $skills)
                {{ $skills->name }}
            @endforeach
            <br>
            @endforeach()
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
@foreach($user->myIndustries as $industry)
   <h4> {{ $industry->title }}</h4>  <br>
    @foreach( $industry->myMajors as $major)
       <B>{{ $major->title }} - </B>
        @foreach($major->mySkills->unique() as $skills)
            {{ $skills->name }}
        @endforeach
        <br>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: @mmmsabeel You should delete () after endforeach